Exercise 4.6 - Topics in Banach space theory (Albiac, Kalton)
I'm trying to solve Exercise 4.6 from Albiac and Kalton's book "Topics in Banach space theory". The exercise is as follows:

(a) If $K$ is extremally disconnected, show that for every bounded lower semicontinuous function $f$, the upper semicontinuous regularization
$$\tilde{f}(s) = \inf \{g(s) : g ∈ C(K), g \geq f\}$$
is continuous.
(b) Deduce that if $K$ is extremally disconnected then $C(K)$ is order-complete.

For completeness of the question, a topological space is extremally disconnected if the closure of every open set is open. Furthermore, altough it is not explicitly said in the problem, from the context I'm assuming that $K$ is compact and Hausdorff.
Assuming (a) I've managed to solve (b), so I'm intereseted in solving (a).
To prove the continuity of $\tilde{f}$ I'm trying to prove that
$$(\tilde{f})^{-1}((a,b)) = \{k \in K: a < \tilde{f}(k)\} \cup \{k \in K: \tilde{f}(k) <b\}$$
is open in $K$.
I have no problem in proving it for the second one, but for the first one I'm a bit stucked. I know it is enough to show that if $k$ satisfies that $\tilde{f}(k)>a$, then $f(k)>a$ (and I think this must be true). To get a contradiction I'm trying to see that if $f(k) \leq a$, then it is possible to construct a $g \in C(K)$ such that $g \geq f$ and $g(k)=a$, so we would get a contradiction because of
$$a < \tilde{f}(k) \leq g(k) = a.$$
I've tried to use Urysohn's lemma to construct the function $g$ and I've observed that, as $K$ is extremally disconected, then for every open set $U$ the indicator functions for $\bar U$ and $K \setminus \bar U$ are continuous, but I'm not able to fully construt a function $g$ that satisfies what I want.
Any help would be apprciated.
I'm on the right track? Any clue on how to get the function $g$? (

Let $K$ be compact, Hausdorff, extremally disconnected. let $f:K\to [0,1]$ be lower semi-continuous (the problem says bounded, but by translating and scaling, we can assume bounded below by $0$ and above by $1$). Define
$$F(x)=\inf \{g(x):g\in C(K),g\geqslant f\}.$$  It is clear that $F(x)\in [0,1]$ for all $x\in K$. It is also clear that $F(x)\geqslant f(x)$ for all $x\in K$.
As stated in the problem, $F$ is called the upper semicontinuous regularization of $f$. Hence we expect $F$ to be upper semicontinuous. As you stated, you can show $F$ is upper semicontinuous without difficulty (and this part is true without using the extremally disconnected hypothesis), so we'll skip that part.
We want to show that $F$ is lower semicontinuous. Fix $b\in \mathbb{R}$ and define $$V_b=F^{-1}((-\infty,b)).$$ $F$ is upper semicontinuous, $V_b$ is open. Since $K$ is extremally disconnected, $\overline{V_b}$ is clopen. Since $\overline{V_b}$ is clopen, $$g(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}b & : x \in \overline{V_b} \\ 1 & : x\in K\setminus \overline{V_b}\end{array}\right.$$ is continuous.
Since $f\leqslant F$, $$V_b\subset f^{-1}((-\infty,b))\subset f^{-1}((-\infty,b]).$$  Since $f$ is lower semicontinuous, $f^{-1}((-\infty,b])$ is closed, so $\overline{V_b}\subset f^{-1}((-\infty,b])$. Therefore $g\geqslant f$, and $F\leqslant g$, from which it follows that $F|_{\overline{V_b}}\leqslant b$. Therefore $$\overline{F^{-1}((-\infty,b))}\subset F^{-1}((-\infty,b]).$$  So for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, since $$\overline{F^{-1}((-\infty,a])}\subset \overline{F^{-1}((-\infty,b))}\subset F^{-1}((-\infty,b])$$ for any $a<b$, it follows that $$\overline{F^{-1}((-\infty,a])}\subset \bigcap_{a<b}F^{-1}((-\infty,b])=F^{-1}((-\infty,a]).$$  Therefore $F^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is closed, and $F$ is lower semicontinuous.
